# tablet screen always takes values from mdpi

Tags: java, android

I need to set text size of edittextbox so,

```
 etsamp.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size));
```

For all types of phones setting screen size works fine ,excepts tablet sized phones,i am using `values,values-mdpi,values-ldpi,values-hdpi,values-xhdpi,values-sw720dp,values-w820dp`

Can anyone help me how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which screen size of tablet you are talking about 
but from your listing i can suggest you one more folder called

```
 values-sw600dp
```

For 7' tablet.